# ServiceStack using interface as template in IReturn<T>

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a question about IReturn.
I found out that

> "Interfaces are most definitely not a perfect valid way to define service interfaces".

But what if despite of that there is a need or idea of doing that.
Is there any way to do that without getting an exception about creating abstract class?

Answer (score 5):

What you've quoted likely refers to WCF's approach of using Interfaces to define Services. WCF [promotes several service anti-patterns](https://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) but this quote has absolutely nothing to do with ServiceStack's `IReturn<T>` interface marker which is a benign interface whose sole purpose is to enable a succinct typed API without having to define the return type on the call-site, e.g:

```
CustomerResponse response = client.Get(new GetCustomer { Id = 1 });
```

If the Request DTO didn't have the `IReturn<T>` marker then every client would need to define the return type on the call-site, e.g:

```
CustomerResponse response = client.Get<CustomerResponse>(new GetCustomer { Id = 1 });
```

Which is unnecessary and a potential source of human error since clients would need to provide the correct response type for each Services whereas if the return type was only defined once on the server (i.e. the authoritative source) then all clients would automatically use the correct response Type since it's embedded on the Request DTO contract - the correct place for it since it defines part of your public Service Contract.

There is no good reason why you wouldn't include an `IReturn<T>` marker, the only valid reason you wouldn't was if your Service returned multiple different Response Types, but that is of itself an anti-pattern and a source of errors that's only detectable at runtime, i.e. the worst kind.

Comment: I think you are missing equal signs in your examples?

Comment: So, is it ok to define IReturn<T> when T is a list too?

Comment: @labilbe It's only used to tell the client what Type should it deserialize the response into and should be compatible with whatever the server response type is, so can be `Poco`, `string`, `byte[]`, `Stream`, `List<Poco>`, etc.

Comment: Can T be an interface? I found that metadata page doesn't work with interface (other than IEnumerable) in IReturn.